# I want to be able to compare revenue for products from two different dates from the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, subquery, aggregate-functions

So I can run two separate queries like this:

```
SELECT date as date1, product as product1, product_id as product_id_1, SUM(revenue) AS rev1 
FROM product_inventory 
WHERE date = '2021-11-17' 
GROUP BY date1 , product1, product_id_1 
ORDER BY rev1 DESC
```

```
SELECT date as date2, product as product2, product_id as product_id_2, SUM(revenue) AS rev2 
FROM product_inventory 
WHERE date = '2022-11-17' 
GROUP BY date2 , product2, product_id_2 
ORDER BY rev2 DESC
```

And this is the output I get for each:

| date1 | product1 | product_id_1 | rev1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-11-17 | adidas samba | 9724 | 6087.7000732421875 |
| 2021-11-17 | nike air max | 5361 | 4918.0 |
| 2021-11-17 | puma suede | 1985 | 3628.1600341796875 |

| date2 | product2 | product_id_2 | rev2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-17 | adidas samba | 9724 | 5829.0 |
| 2022-11-17 | nike air max | 5361 | 4841.864013671875 |
| 2022-11-17 | puma suede | 1985 | 5404.4140625 |

How can I query the db in a way that would pull the date2 and rev2 column into one single output like this?

| date1 | product1 | product_id_1 | rev1 | date2 | rev2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-11-17 | adidas samba | 9724 | 6087.7000732421875 | 2022-11-17 | 5829.0 |
| 2021-11-17 | nike air max | 5361 | 4918.0 | 2022-11-17 | 4841.864013671875 |
| 2021-11-17 | puma suede | 1985 | 3628.1600341796875 | 2022-11-17 | 5404.4140625 |

I tried this query:

```
SELECT A.date1, A.product1, A.rev1, B.date2, B.product2, B.rev2 FROM
(
SELECT date as date1, product as product1, product_id as product_id_1, SUM(revenue) AS rev1 FROM product_inventory WHERE date = '2021-11-17' GROUP BY date1 , product1, product_id_1 ORDER BY rev1 DESC
) A,
(
SELECT date as date2, product as product2, product_id as product_id_2, SUM(revenue) AS rev2 FROM product_inventory WHERE date = '2022-11-17' GROUP BY date2, product2, product_id_2 ORDER BY rev2 DESC
) B;
```

but I get this output

| date1 | product1 | rev1 | date2 | product2 | rev2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-11-17 | puma suede | 3628.1600341796875 | 2022-11-17 | adidas samba shoes | 5829.0 |
| 2021-11-17 | nike air max | 4918.0 | 2022-11-17 | adidas samba shoes | 5829.0 |
| 2021-11-17 | adidas samba | 6087.7000732421875 | 2022-11-17 | adidas samba shoes | 5829.0 |
| 2021-11-17 | puma suede | 3628.1600341796875 | 2022-11-17 | puma suede | 5404.4140625 |
| 2021-11-17 | nike air max | 4918.0 | 2022-11-17 | puma suede | 5404.4140625 |
| 2021-11-17 | adidas samba | 6087.7000732421875 | 2022-11-17 | puma suede | 5404.4140625 |
| 2021-11-17 | puma suede | 3628.1600341796875 | 2022-11-17 | nike air max | 4841.864013671875 |
| 2021-11-17 | nike air max | 4918.0 | 2022-11-17 | nike air max | 4841.864013671875 |
| 2021-11-17 | adidas samba | 6087.7000732421875 | 2022-11-17 | nike air max | 4841.864013671875 |

It's like the number of records gets squared.

Comment: yes, `from tablea, tableb` inspects every possible combination of tablea and tableb rows, not at all what you want.  what does `select version();` show?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Can you please show us the dataset that you are starting from, and that generates the intermediate output of the first two queries? Also, a few explanations about what the two queries are meant to do, wand why one is sorting on `rev1` and the other on `rev2`, would be helpful. Maybe you just don't need two (sub)queries? It is hard to tell so far.

Answer (score 1):

You want to compare the revenues of the same product on two different dates. You can do this without subqueries or `WITH`, using conditional aggregation:

```
select product_id, product,
    sum(case when date = '2021-11-17' then revenue end) as rev_2021_11_17,
    sum(case when date = '2022-11-17' then revenue end) as rev_2022_11_17
from product_inventory 
where date in ('2021-11-17', '2022-11-17')
group by product_id, product
```

I don't really see the need to return the dates in the resultset; they are know to the client already, since they are given as paramters to the query. But it you like, you either hardcode them in the `SELECT` clause, or use `MIN` and `MAX`.

Answer (score 0):

Your first two queries are practically identical. Only the aliases in them are different. That makes the task a bit pointless. But if we assume you want to **join** the data from the two result sets, here is how you could do it:

```
SELECT t1.date, t1.product, t1.product_id, t2.date, t2.product_id, ...
FROM
  (SELECT ... FROM product_inventory WHERE ... GROUP BY ...) AS t1
JOIN
  (SELECT ... FROM product_inventory WHERE ... GROUP BY ...) AS t2
ON t1.product_id = t2.product_id AND t1.date = t2.date
ORDER BY ...
```

Also, MySQL 8 introduced a feature called [Common Table Expressions (CTE)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions), which might be a nice alternative to the above query, in that it allows you to separate the SELECT queries of the two result sets you want to join. So with CTE you could write something like this:

```
WITH 
  t1 AS
  (SELECT ... FROM product_inventory WHERE ... GROUP BY ...),
  t2 AS
  (SELECT ... FROM product_inventory WHERE ... GROUP BY ...),
SELECT t1.date, t1.product, t1.product_id, t2.date, t2.product_id, ...
FROM t1      
JOIN t2 ON t1.product_id = t2.product_id AND t1.date = t2.date
ORDER BY ...
```

Note that in both queries, I've extracted the `ORDER BY` from the two result sets and have put it in the "final" SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JOIN on product_id like this:

```
WITH DATE_1 AS (
SELECT date as date1, product as product1, product_id as product_id_1, SUM(revenue) AS rev1 
  FROM product_inventory 
 WHERE date = '2021-10-17' 
 GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
),
DATE_2 AS (
SELECT date as date2, product as product2, product_id as product_id_2, SUM(revenue) AS rev2 
  FROM product_inventory 
 WHERE date = '2021-11-17' 
 GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
)
SELECT D1.*, D2.*
  FROM DATE_1 D1
       INNER JOIN DATE_2 D2
          ON D1.product_id_1 = D2.product_id_2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your informations, you can do the `WITH` from sql, it will generate "fake table" that you can use to do some others operation

```sql
-- Your first query that I put in a "fake table" named first_date
WITH first_date AS (
    SELECT date as date1, product as product1, product_id as product_id_1, SUM(revenue) AS rev1 
    FROM product_inventory 
    WHERE date = '2021-11-17' 
    GROUP BY date1 , product1, product_id_1 
    ORDER BY rev1 DESC
),
-- Your second query that I put in a "fake table" named second_date
second_date AS (
    SELECT date as date2, product as product2, product_id as product_id_2, SUM(revenue) AS rev2 
    FROM product_inventory 
    WHERE date = '2022-11-17' 
    GROUP BY date2 , product2, product_id_2 
    ORDER BY rev2 DESC
)
-- First we get the products in both "fake tables"
SELECT a.*, b.date2, b.rev2
FROM first_date a
INNER JOIN second_date b ON a.product_id_1 = b.product_id_2
UNION
-- Then only in the first "fake table"
SELECT c.*, NULL, NULL
FROM first_date c
LEFT JOIN second_date d ON c.product_id_1 = d.product_id_2
WHERE d.product_id_2 IS NULL
UNION
-- Then only in the second "fake table"
SELECT NULL, f.product2, f.product_id_2, NULL, f.date2, f.rev2
FROM first_date e
RIGHT JOIN second_date f ON e.product_id_1 = f.product_id_2
WHERE e.product_id_1 IS NULL;
```

Comment: This worked! But what if there is a product that exists for one date, but not the other? I have a product for 2022-11-17 that didn't exist for 2021-11-17 that I still want to pull.

Comment: I just edit my work, you can test with this